# Why is the hash of an object staying the same when I change its data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, cryptojs

I have this code to hash an object.

I am saving this hash as a key in redis with a timeout but even if I change something in that incoming request object it is generating the same hash and redis shows there is same key already there.

Does this package have some trouble on hashing or does my code have any problem?

```
const asyncMiddleware = require('../middlewares/async');
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
exports.hash = asyncMiddleware(async (hashRequest) => {
    try {
        var hash = CryptoJS.SHA256(hashRequest).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
        return hash;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error : ", error);
    }
});
```

Comment: [can't reproduce](https://replit.com/@lucakiebel/TechnologicalDigitalAbstraction#index.js). How do you pass the `hashRequest` variable to the function?

Comment: Through postman request I will call an api and that req body is given to this function as named `hashRequest`

Comment: Can you try with it a json object with minute difference and check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass an Object to the SHA256 Method, you may only pass strings and [WordArrays](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-hashing-input).

When you pass an object, cryptojs will run `.toString()` on it, which will always give the same output (`[object Object]`), and thus the same hash.

```js
console.log(({a:1,b:1}).toString())
console.log(({a:1,b:2}).toString())
```

If you want to hash Objects, `JSON.stringify()` them:

```js
const asyncMiddleware = require('../middlewares/async');
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
exports.hash = asyncMiddleware(async (hashRequest) => {
    try {
        return CryptoJS.SHA256(JSON.stringify(hashRequest)).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error : ", error);
    }
});
```

See my [repl](https://replit.com/@lucakiebel/TechnologicalDigitalAbstraction#index.js) again, for the difference.

Comment: For your future questions: Please always include a sample of the input to your program.

Comment: For sure but in question I had mention I had tried to hash an object